# Group by query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table with create_dt and order_type, now I want count of different orders on different dates.

For e.g. on 22nd March, 2016 I have orders with count(each count means different row) of orders of type_1(2), type_2(3) and no 23rd March, 2016 I have type_1(5) and type_2(3) ordered.

The expected output should be

```
Order_type  count(order_type) create_dt
type_1      2                 22-03-2016
type_1      5                 23-03-2016
type_2      3                 22-03-2016
type_2      3                 23-03-2016
```

Can someone help here in this?

Answer (score 1):

Thats a simple group by query :

```
SELECT s.order_type,count(*) as type,t.create_Dt
FROM create_dt t
INNER JOIN order_type  s
 ON(t.order_id = s.order_id)
GROUP BY s.order_type,t.create_dt
```

And if you have order_type column in create_Dt you don't need to join

```
SELECT t.order_type,count(*) as type,trunc(t.create_dt)
FROM create_dt t
GROUP BY t.order_type,trunc(t.create_dt)
```

**EDIT:** If I understood you correctly :

```
SELECT s.order_Type,count(*) as Type,t.create_dt
FROM order_type s
LEFT OUTER JOIN create_dt 
 ON(s.order_type = t.order_type)
GROUP BY s.order_Type,t.create_dt
```

If you want the month without record to appear as 0, change the count to this:

```
count(t.order_type)
```

Comment: Create_dt and order_type is of same table. The problem with below query is it is returning me the rows which having always a count of 1 on each date as this is become unique combination. I already tried that but it's not working

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following, try my updated answer @KulbhushanSingh

Comment: Use trunc on date column to group by days instead of seconds.

Comment: Yea, that could be the problem

Comment: I used to_char(create_dt,'DD-MON-YYYY') and it started working.. Thank You for the help

Comment: @KulbhushanSingh You can also use trunc(create_dt)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   trunc(create_dt),
         Order_type,
         count(order_type)
from     table_name
group by trunc(create_dt),
         Order_type;
```

Use `trunc()` to truncate the time-component of the `create_dt` column to midnight so that the rows on the same day will have identical date values and can be grouped by days.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT create_dt, Order_type, count(order_type) 
from table_name 
group by create_dt, Order_type;
```

Comment: just change the order of the rows according the question